# DockerDesktopVM can't start due to Hyper-V

Tags: docker, virtual-machines, hyper-v

For some reason I keep getting the error that "DockerDesktopVM" can't be started because a Hyper-V component isn't running, but how do I change that?

I found people adding commands like `hypervisor.cpuid.v0` into their `vmx` files, but I dont  have access to that, but is this really the problem here?

[image: Error message]

Hyper-V is enabled?

[image: Hyper-V Enabled already]

I've tried to follow this guide, but might have missed somthing?
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/

Note: This is a windows VM, and I dont have access to the VM files. I was trying to do this (3:20): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABfiJqNjBwo&t=200s&ab_channel=TechAreaNetwork

I also read this:
You're using Docker Machine in your Windows VM, which is actually going to create a Linux VM inside the Windows VM on your Windows PC. You can do that, but you need to enable nested virtualization - which I'm not sure you can do in Parallels 7.

But again I don't have access to this remote windows machine